# Remove product link from WooCommerce archives if the product has no description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce archive pages, the product image and the title are linked to the single-product page, like `domain/product/{product-name}/`.

I would like, if the product does not have a description for example,  to remove that link.

I tried the following:

```
add_action("template_redirect", "disable_single_product_access", 1);

function disable_single_product_access() {
    if (is_singular('product')) {
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
        $has_variations = $product->is_type('variable');
        $has_price = $product->get_price();
        $has_description = $product->get_description();

        if (!$has_variations || !$has_price || !$has_description) {
            // If product has no description or something above remove redirection
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried:

- removing the `href` and redirecting with `wp_redirect`,
- setting the `href` to redirect to an empty link.

None worked.